# Will substrate chains continue to support native execution?

Tags: executor

It looks like all the recent PRs around removing native execution are for removing native execution from polkadot and parachains. I wanted to confirm that the plan is to keep native execution available for substrate users? I'm conscious that various chains out there  building on substrate depend on using native execution for one reason or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nay: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/14387

(or at least not unless risc-v comes on the scene...)